# Get All record group by date and hour if any column have null value

Tags: c#, linq, entity

I have two tables.

The first is open count:

```
openDate                       OpenCount
2014-08-01 07:00:06.163          1
2014-08-01 09:00:11.873          1 
2014-08-02 03:00:42.623          1
2014-08-02 05:00:48.363          1
2014-08-02 08:01:15.243          1
2014-08-03 07:01:16.507          1
```

The second is click count

```
clickDate                       Count
2014-08-01 08:00:06.163           1
2014-08-01 09:00:11.873           1 
2014-08-01 11:00:42.623           1
2014-08-01 15:00:48.363           1
2014-08-03 07:01:15.243           1
2014-08-11 07:01:16.507           1
```

I  want 2 hour wise, 4 hour wise, week wise and all time wise

I have used the following code

```
int groupHours = 2;

int take = 12;
if (type == 1 )
{ groupHours = 2; }
else if (type == 2 )
{ groupHours = 4; }
else if (type == 7 )
{
    groupHours = 24;
    take = 7;
}
else if( type == 0)
{

    take = 12;
}



var queryOpen = objEmailOpen.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(row => new
            {

                Date = row.openDate.Value.Date,
                Hour = (((row.openDate.Value.Hour) / groupHours)) * groupHours
            })
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        Date = grp.Key.Date.AddHours(grp.Key.Hour),
        Hour = grp.Key.Hour,
        OpenCount = grp.Count()
    }).OrderBy(m => m.Date).Take(take).ToList();

var queryClick = objEmailClick.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(row => new
        {
            Date = row.clickedDate.Value.Date,
            Hour = (((row.clickedDate.Value.Hour) / groupHours)) * groupHours
        })
        .Select(grp => new
        {
            Date = grp.Key.Date.AddHours(grp.Key.Hour),
            Hour = grp.Key.Hour,
            ClickCount = grp.Count()
        }).OrderBy(m => m.Date).ToList();


var timeWise = (from m in queryOpen
                join n in queryClick on new { m.Date, m.Hour } equals new { n.Date, n.Hour }
                select new
                {
                    date = Convert.ToDateTime(m.Date),
                    open = m.OpenCount,
                    click = n.ClickCount
                }).ToList().Take(12);

var result = new
{ 
    timeWise = timeWise
};
```

But this will not give the proper result, if any time interval click count is null (0) then it will not show that time interval record and this will also not work for all time records.

I want that all time records in only the 12th row, maybe it takes 1 day time interval or many day or month.

But the result contains a proper date time interval like (If the time interval is 2 hours):

```
date                   openCount      clickcount
2018-8-1 07:00:00        15                 3
2018-8-1 09:00:00        3                  0
2018-8-1 011:00:00       12                 2
```

Comment: You need to use the algorithm Bell Labs developed years ago to get counts of telephone usage by time periods.  To handle the null cases you have to build a table of time periods and then put the data into the times periods.

Comment: can u give me link for that algorithm

Comment: There is no real algorithm.  If you want hours then create a table with 24 rows one for each hour.  Then join your table with the new table of 24 hours using a left outer join (to get null).

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of time intervals like code below.  Then combine you table with the list using left outer join to get the nulls

```
            DateTime startDay = DateTime.Now.Date;
            DateTime endDay = startDay.AddDays(1);

            int intervalMinutes = 60;

             DateTime  timeCounter = startDay;

             List<DateTime> intervals = new List<DateTime>();
             while (timeCounter < endDay)
             {
                 intervals.Add(timeCounter);
                 timeCounter = timeCounter.AddMinutes(intervalMinutes);
             }
```

Comment: You have something against `Enumerable.Range`? :)

Comment: Yes,  Enumerable range is for integers an I needed TIME.

Comment: `var intervals = Enumerable.Range(0, 24).Select(n => startDate.AddMinutes(n*60)).ToList();`

Comment: `var intervals = Enumerable.Range(0, 24).Select(n => startDate.AddHours(n)).ToList();`